# How do I send messages from Android to Unity (with VR)? (UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage doesn't work)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, integration, virtual-reality, oculus

-> Summary:

I want to send messages from AndroidStudio - Code to Unity - Normal way doesn't seem to be working.

---

-> What I tried:

I have two projects in Unity3D. They are exactly the same, except that one of them is set up for the Oculus Gear Vr...
Then I export (Android) both of these Projects and open them as AndroidStudio Projects.
When i run these now both work exactly as expected !

But when i try to use the UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage - method, the method seems not to be executed in the app with the setup vor VR...
The app doesnt crash, it doesnt show any errors in LogCat and i tried to catch any Throwable but that didnt work either...

(On the App with no VR setup the exact same lines of codes works ...)

---

-> Android - Code:

```
public class UnityPlayerActivity extends Activity {
   [...]

   onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      [...] //code generated by Unity

      try{
         Log.d("mDEBUG", "Test Android1");
         UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("AndroidCommunication", "AndroidStudioInit", "false");
         Log.d("mDEBUG", "Test Android2");
      }catch(Throwable e){
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   //Function used by Unity - Code
   public void unityLog(String msg){
      Log.d("mDEBUG", "Unity: " + msg);
   }

   [...]
}
```

---

-> Unity - Code:

```
public void AndroidStudioInit(string flag)
{
   bool sendCurCameraRotation = bool.Parse(flag);
   
   AndroidJavaClass unityPlayerClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
   AndroidJavaObject unityPlayerActivity = unityPlayerClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

   unityPlayerActivity.Call("unityLog", "AndroidStudio - Unity - Init");
}
```

---

**-> Expected Outputs**:

> For both apps it should print in Logcat:
>
> 1. "[...] D/mDEBUG: Test Android1"
> 2. "[...] D/mDEBUG: Unity: AndroidStudio - Unity - Init"
> 3. "[...] D/mDEBUG: Test Android2"

---

**-> Actual Results**:

> **For app without setup for VR**:
>
> 1. "[...] D/mDEBUG: Test Android1"
> 2. "[...] D/mDEBUG: Unity: AndroidStudio - Unity - Init"
> 3. "[...] D/mDEBUG: Test Android2"
>
> **For app with VR**:
>
> 1. "[...] D/mDEBUG: Test Android1"
> 2. "[...] D/mDEBUG: Test Android2"

---

There are also no errors and the Unity App doesnt crash... it just "seems to ignore" the function call...

Comment: Please post your UnityPlayerActivity code.

Comment: I already provided the "Android - Code", above and below is still the same from the generated Unity code. (The "Android - Code" is the "UnityPlayerActivity - class - code")

Answer (score 1):

Ok it seems I know what the problem is and I think it can't really be helped...

I was sending a message to Unity like this:

```
mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
setContentView(mUnityPlayer);
mUnityPlayer.requestFocus();

UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("AndroidCommunication", "AndroidStudioInit", "false");
```

And normally Unity will store the message in a queue to execute it after Unity has started properly.

That works for the App **without Vr** enabled just fine.

But **with Vr** mode enabled a screen will first show up on your device (something like "Put your device into the Gear Vr ...").
And I think it somehow messes up with the message sending...

So Unity will only execute messages after proper starting (After window "Made by Unity" went by).

To remember: Don't send Messages until unity has completely started if you use Vr... If you still want to execute code on start you can try to build a method in Unity that will notify the android code that Unity has finished !

Cheers !